# Spring Security Error No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to Implement spring security on my Spring MVC web application.  with basic authentication functionality. I have read most of the similar issues that already posted but still I couldn't find a solution. I got error when trying to run my application. I have imported spring security dependencies in my pom.xml file and I have annotated @EnableWebSecurity in my ConfiguracionSpringSecurity class but is still not working I can't find issue. Somebody can help me?, please

**Error**

```
2018-02-22 09:54:59 DEBUG DelegatingFilterProxy:208 - Initializing filter 'springSecurityFilterChain'
feb 22, 2018 9:54:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
GRAVE: Excepción arrancando filtro springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:236)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5340)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

feb 22, 2018 9:54:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
         <spring.version>4.3.10.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
        <postgres.version>42.1.3</postgres.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security  END-->
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>Sistema Administrativo</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- SECURITY -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- END SECURITY -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/resources/application.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
<!--        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound"><value>true</value></property> -->
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/resources/application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


        <!-- DataSource -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
    </bean>


    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.andetek.model"></property>
    </bean>

      <!-- Transaction -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service, DAO -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.andetek" />

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <!-- This makes /META-INF/persistence.xml is no longer necessary -->
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.andetek.model" />
      <!-- JpaVendorAdapter implementation for Hibernate EntityManager.
           Exposes Hibernate's persistence provider and EntityManager extension interface -->
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- SECURITY -->
   <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy"/>
   <!-- END SECURITY -->

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.andetek.repository" factory-class="org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.repository.DataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"></jpa:repositories>

</beans>
```

**ConfiguracionSpringSecurity.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ConfiguracionSpringSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Fernando").password("1234").roles("AGENTE");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Mulder").password("fox").roles("AGENTE_ESPECIAL");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Scully").password("dana").roles("AGENTE_ESPECIAL");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Skinner").password("walter").roles("DIRECTOR");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/views/login/login.jsp")
            .failureUrl("/views/nuestro-login.jsp?login_error");

        http
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/views/desconectado.jsp");

        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/views/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/css/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/img/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('AGENTE_ESPECIAL')");

        http
            .csrf().disable();

        http
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/views/acceso-denegado.jsp");

    }

}
```

Comment: Where did you read that you have to write `<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy"/>`? That makes no sense. You have to create the `FilterChainProxy` bean not another delegate.

Comment: I read it in another post, where they had that bean.
how i create the filterChainProxy?

Comment: If you use Java configuration you do not need that line. Remove it. But I guess you will get some more errors, because I can't see that you load your Java configuration in your XMl configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the namespaces from the servlet-context.xml file with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: I've edited the post with removing the explicit versions of spring that you should use.